# PDO exception trying to insert data into a blob

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

I am trying to insert a very large JSON object into a blob and I am getting an exception error indicating invalid parameter number 'not defined'.

code:

```
<?php




        session_start();
        require_once('sconfig.php');
        require_once('mail/config.php');
        try{
                $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

                $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                        'email' => $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'],
                        'card'  => $token
                ));
                $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                        'customer' => $customer->id,
                        'amount' => $_SESSION['PLAN'],
                        'currency' => 'usd'
                ));

        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Handle your exception fool!";
        }
        //var_dump($customer);
        echo "<br>";
        //var_dump(json_decode($customer));
        echo "<br>";

        //echo $_SESSION['PLAN'];

        $pdo = new PDO(
                'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE,
                DB_USER,
                DB_PASSWORD
        );
        //here we insert plan into the database following purchase
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
        $session_var = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];


        //ATTENTION!!!  All of these variable need to be changed when price gets changed
        if($_SESSION['PLAN'] === '3500'){
                $plan_var = 1;
                echo $plan_var;
                $sql = 'UPDATE accounting SET active = 1, plan = :plan_var WHERE id = :session_var';
                $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO transactions (customer_object, charge_object) VALUES(:customer, :charge)';
        }
        else if($_SESSION['PLAN'] === '2500'){
                $plan_var = 2;
                echo $plan_var;
                $sql = 'UPDATE accounting SET active = 1, plan = :plan_var WHERE id = :session_var';
                $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO transactions (customer_object, charge_object) VALUES(:customer, :charge)';
        }
        else if($_SESSION['PLAN'] === 'NULL'){
                echo "Call a Dr. Something bad happened, or the programmer needs to be fired";

                header("location: ../index.php?p=failed");
        }
        else {
                echo "This looks like a paid invoice. Thank you!";
                $plan_var = 9;
                echo '<br>';
                echo $plan_var;
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
                $sql = 'UPDATE accounting SET plan = :plan_var WHERE id = :session_var';
                $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO transactions (invoice_num) VALUES(:invoice_num)';
                //header("location: ../index.php?p=success");
        }

        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
        $statement->bindParam(':plan_var', $plan_var, PDO::PARAM_STR, 1);
        $statement->bindParam(':session_var', $session_var, PDO::PARAM_STR, 1);
        $statement2->bindParam(':customer', $customer, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $statement2->bindParam(':charge', $charge, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $statement2->bindParam(':invoice_num', $_SESSION['INVOICE_NUM'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $user = $statement->execute();
        $user = $statement2->execute();

        var_dump($statement);

        //header("location: ../index.php?p=success");

        //echo $token;
?>
```

The ERROR I am receiving is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /usr/home/nyctelecomm/www/pages/scharge.php:79 Stack trace: #0 /usr/home/nyctelecomm/www/pages/scharge.php(79): PDOStatement->bindParam(':customer', Object(Stripe\Customer), 3) #1 {main} thrown in /usr/home/nyctelecomm/www/pages/scharge.php on line 79
```

How do I get blob data into a mysql database using pdo?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 
'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: 
Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in 

/usr/home/nyctelecomm/www/pages/scharge.php:79 Stack trace: 

#0 /usr/home/nyctelecomm/www/pages/scharge.php(79): 
        PDOStatement->bindParam(':customer', Object(Stripe\Customer), 3) 
#1 {main} thrown in /usr/home/nyctelecomm/www/pages/scharge.php on line 79
```

It looks like PHP is stumbling over the following line (#79)

```
$statement2->bindParam(':customer', $customer, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

My guess if you're trying to bind the parameter `:customer` into a SQL statment that doesn't have the parameter `:customer` defined.  Looking at all the possible values of `$sql2`

```
$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO transactions 
(customer_object, charge_object) VALUES(:customer, :charge)';

$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO transactions 
(customer_object, charge_object) VALUES(:customer, :charge)';

$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO transactions (invoice_num) VALUES(:invoice_num)';
```

It seems like you're not always binding a `:customer` parameter.

I'd refactor your code to ensure you're not binding parameters that don't exist in your SQL.

Comment: I tried doing the two queries as a compound query but that didn't work out very well either. What do you mean by 'refactor'?  I do not understand your solution.